# how to Create PPT slides Programatically using OpenXml in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create PPT slides Programatically based on NUmber of Images,

iam using VS2010, and OpenXml,

THanks in advance

Comment: _Did you tried anything so far?_ Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I tried many ways please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757888/add-slides-to-ppt-dynamically-in-asp-net-using-openoffice-xml                       and also through this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743948/export-ms-chartimage-to-ppt-in-asp-net  but no luck :( help me please its Urgent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [MSDN link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718), you will get some idea.

[One more resource.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj159403%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: that is Working fine in Local host, but when i publish in IIS it's not working, so i have choosen OpenXml, but unable to create Slides dynamically

Comment: @Vikramsing Shinde: Thanks its working now..StackOVerflow Rocks